# XmlTransient annotation on getter only?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xmltransient

I am trying to unmarshal an XML into an object that I expect should have a certain field. However, I do not want to marshal that object into an XML that contains it. What I like would be similar to this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User {

    private String name;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getName() {
        return this.name
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

However, this would not work due to the conflicting annotations, as I can't use any other XML annotations with `@XmlTransient`. I have also tried to add the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the field itself instead of the getter and have set this option:

`XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

In addition, I kept the `@XmlElement` annotation on the setter, and that did absolutely nothing in terms of excluding the field from being marshalled.

I would like to keep the `@XmlElement` annotation, since I like being able to translate a field with a different name (here it is just a capitalization difference) into whichever field I want.

I also cannot delete the getter, as I do use it in the application.

Given that, I don't know what my options are at this point, other than writing an adapter (which I could do, but if there is another solution, I'd rather not use a custom adapter because of this one field). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem lies in the idea itself: `@XmlTransient` tells the marshaller to completely ignore that field/property when doing its job, so I'd guess it's not what you're looking for, as you wouldn't want to (and couldn't anyway) set a custom name for the marshalled element if you wanted to omit it in the first place.

Another point is that with JAXB, public getters/setters are paired with their respective counterparts, so the annotations applied to both are "merged" when read (hence why you can't use `@XmlTransient` in the getter and `@XmlElement` in the setter at the same time), and thus their positions are also interchangeable.

Also, just for clarity, `@XmlAccessorType` only interferes in the default handling of *`public`* members. If the field or method in question is *not* `public`, it won't affect how it will be handled by default.

Now for the solutions:

- If you want to omit it all:

  - With `private` field and `public` getter/setter, just use `@XmlTransient` once in the getter or setter and nothing else.

    ```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "User")
    public class User {

        private String name;

        @XmlTransient
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    ```
  - If both are `public`, use `@XmlTransient` once in the field and once again in either getter or setter.

    ```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "User")
    public class User {

        @XmlTransient
        public String name;

        @XmlTransient
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    ```
- If instead you want to keep it with a custom name:

  - If the field is `private`, use only `@XmlElement` once in the getter or setter.

    ```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "User")
    public class User {

        private String name;

        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    ```
  - If both field and accessors are public (and there's no `@XmlAccessorType` or it's set to `XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER`), then you'll have to use `@XmlTransient` in either field or getter/setter and `@XmlElement` in the other (they'll be interchangeable if all the methods do is just reading/writing the value, as in this case).

    ```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "User")
    public class User {

        @XmlTransient
        public String name;

        @XmlElement(name = "Name")
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
    ```